# nodejs express url rewrite?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am new to nodejs and just started learning it. I started with express. Everything's good but have a question not sure if this needs to be URL rewrite or URL redirect.
views folder looks like below, (jade files)

```
views
  - index
  - news
  - videos
```

The first page definitely is index, url is localhost:3000. Now I want my news page to be the index page, so when I enter localhost:3000 or localhost:3000/news, I want always to see the news.jade content. but I don't want to duplicate news.jade to index.jade. So I think the best thing is to have a urlwrite, then either localhost:3000 or localhost:3000/news will get news.jade content. 
if a url rewirte needed to achieve my goal, is below code is a good example?

```
app.use('/news', function(req, res, next){
    var old_url = req.url;
    req.url = '/index';
    next();
});
```

I searched a while, but didn't really get an answer, could someone please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have scaffolded using [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator), then it would create a `routes` folder that handles all the routing code. Refer [this link](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to know more on express generator.

You have to edit the index.js file in that folder

```
   router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     res.render('news');
   });
```

When ever the application receives a / request that is localhost:3000/ it will render the news file.

If you have any more doubt you can refer the manual here http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

**Edit** - Fix typo

Comment: Express does not have any default routes folder. However, you are free to structure your apps the way that makes sense to you. To create the above scaffolding, people tend to use a generator, like  https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator.