# How to create a webpage that is only an image and nothing else

Tags: html, image

How does one create a webpage that is only an image and nothing else? For example, on the website https://just-read.it/, the index page is an image and nothing else. It displays like you've opened a direct link to an image, not like putting an `<img/>` tag in an html file. How can this be done?

Comment: It isn't HTML. The server simply served an image to that URL.

Comment: This can be implemented differently on different web servers, but as @daniel-smit pointed out what you're really trying to do it write a redirect rule that sends the user to your image file

Answer (score 2):

For Apache/PHP servers, this can be done through the .htaccess file.

Pages can be redirected without changing the address in the URL bar. In this case it would be redirected to the image.

See [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-) for more details (instead of redirecting to a .html or .php page it would be to an image).

[This method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098136/nodejs-express-url-rewrite) is an alternative for Node.js.

Comment: So this would not be possible on a static site builder like Github Pages?

Comment: There seems to be a way. Github Pages doesn't support .htaccess files, but something like [this](https://lea.verou.me/2016/11/url-rewriting-with-github-pages/) might work, or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446435/is-there-an-alternative-to-htaccess-for-github-pages) for other ideas. I haven't done it personally though.

Answer (score 0):

You could two this two ways.

1. Create a webpage with an image. Like this:

```html
<img src="example.jpg" alt="example image">
```

2. Create a page that redirects to an image

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  location.replace("http://pages.artyserver.com/bee.jpg")
}
</script>
```

Hope this helped!